# After running the GStreamer rtsp client program for a long time, free command's buff/cache increased a lot

Tags: gstreamer, nvidia-jetson

I wrote a rtsp client program using gstreamer.

After running the program for a day, free command's buff/cache  increased a lot.
Initially, this value was about 600, which was about 4000.

Why has it increased and is not released automatically?

```
$ free
              total        used        free      shared    buff/cache   available

Mem:           7851        2162        5002          32         687        5482
```